# Evaluate Derivative of Function at a Point Python 2.7

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following function:

```
import sympy as sp
def inverted(q, m, a, nu):
    return (-1)**(m+1)*(a/m)**m*sp.exp(m)*q**(-nu)*sp.diff(1/(sp.sqrt(a**2+q**2))*(sp.sqrt(a**2+q**2)-a)**(nu), a, m+1)
```

I want to define some lambda function such that

```
f100 = lambda a, q: inverted(q, 100, a, 0)
```

However, when I try to examine

```
q = sp.symbols('q')
f100(1000.0, q)
```

I get the following output:

```
ValueError: 
Can't calculate 101st derivative wrt 10.
```

Obviously, what is happening is when I call `f100(1000.0, q)`, the function refers back to `inverted` and the issue arises. I was hoping for a way around this.

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have to make `a` a variable first so `diff` works. It doesn't work if you fix `a` before (I think because you differentiate with respect to `a`). You can substitute `a` with `1000` afterwards.

```
import sympy as sp
def inverted(q, m, a, nu):
    return (-1)**(m+1)*(a/m)**m*sp.exp(m)*q**(-nu)*sp.diff(1/(sp.sqrt(a**2+q**2))*(sp.sqrt(a**2+q**2)-a)**(nu), a, m+1)

f100 = lambda a, q: inverted(q, 100, a, 0)

q, a = sp.symbols('q, a')
print(f100(a, q).subs(a, 1000))
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks!